# Automated Scrolling Excel Data

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have built a large macro to parse a live data feed that fills into excel.  The macro itself is activated from a `Worksheet_Change` event.  The plan is to display the changing data on a tv on the wall in our office so we are aware of what's occurring in our industry in real time.

The issue i'm struggling with is that this macro can execute as rapidly as a few times every second or once every few minutes: how do I display this data so that it is visible without someone having to scroll the excel sheet down every T(x).  If the it was more T(15m) then that wouldn't be such a problem, but as it stands it could be T(1) and that's not very feasible.  I have searched google as well as the stack community and can't find any similar issues to this.  Any thoughts?

**The data feeds in row by row so excel would need to scroll down.

**Worksheet Change Event In Sheet**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    If target.Rows(1).Cells.Count = 18 Then

        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

        'Turn off event handling so if anything is changed, sub procedure will not be triggered
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim initialTradeStructure As String, finalTradeStructure As String, rawStructure As String
        Dim nonLiveBlock As Boolean

        Select Case LCase(target.Cells(1, 3).Value2)

            'RFQs
            Case "requestforquote"

                'Do Nothing....no analysis of RFQs is necessary....will be filtered later

            'Screen Trades
            Case "globextrades"

                rawStructure = target.Item(1, 2)

                initialTradeStructure = Right(rawStructure, Len(rawStructure) - 4)

                'Bulk of analaysis conducted in analsyis engine to keep worksheet code clean/short
                finalTradeStructure = OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(initialTradeStructure, target)

            'Block screen represented as Multileg in datafeed structure
            Case "block"

                If UCase(target.Item(1, 17).Text) = "TRUE" Then

                    nonLiveBlock = True

                    rawStructure = target.Item(1, 2)

                    initialTradeStructure = Right(rawStructure, Len(rawStructure) - 4)

                    'Bulk of analysis conducted in analysis engine to keep worksheet code clean/short
                    finalTradeStructure = OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(initialTradeStructure, target)

                ElseIf UCase(target.Item(1, 17).Text) = "FALSE" And UCase(target.Item(1, 16).Text) = "FALSE" Then

                    'Live block trade
                    rawStructure = target.Item(1, 2)

                    initialTradeStructure = Right(rawStructure, Len(rawStructure) - 4)

                    finalTradeStructure = OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(initialTradeStructure, target)

                Else

                    'Do Nothing....No analysis of single block legs is necessary

                End If

            End Select

        If Not finalTradeStructure = "Nothing" And Not finalTradeStructure = "" Then

            finalTradeStructure = finalTradeStructure & " | Trades " & target.Item(1, 9).Value2 & " " & "| " & target.Item(1, 10).Value2 & "x"

            WTIAmericanOptionData.Cells(target.Row, 1) = finalTradeStructure

        End If
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Private Sub ToggleEventHandler()

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Well you could insert the new line of data at the top, avoiding scrolling altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = target.Row
```

I am curious though, what happens when you get to the end?

Comment: Apologies but I thought the question was "how do I display this data so that it is visible without someone having to scroll the excel sheet down every ..." . My answer is simply 'ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = target.Row' and am asking what happens when they get to the end? But clearly one of us misunderstood the question. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yes it does but it selects it. If he's moving as fast as less than 1 second you don't want to select anything just move around.

Comment: Agreed (and already up-voted) - multiple ways to skin this trivial cat though.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote, trying to get to your level!